# xml parsing from String

Tags: java, xml, blackberry

I am parsing a xml the data is coming from a String. i am using the following code for parsing:-

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
    .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory
    .newDocumentBuilder();
    docBuilder.isValidating();
    ByteArrayInputStream ba= new ByteArrayInputStream(connect.content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    doc = docBuilder.parse(ba);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList locationStatus = doc.getElementsByTagName("street");
    for (int i = 0; i < locationStatus.getLength(); i++) {
        Node locationValue = locationStatus.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0);
        _node.addElement(locationValue.getNodeValue());
    }      
    String [] nodeString = new String[_node.size()];
    _node.copyInto(nodeString);
    add(new LabelField(nodeString.length+""));
```

But this code is giving error , i dont no where the error is.

please Help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the details of the error? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Can you post the error message and stack trace?

Comment: It would also help to see the XML you are trying to parse

Comment: illeagale Argument Exception is coming

Answer (score 0):

Use XStream or JAXB

Comment: Is this even available on BlackBerry ?

Answer (score 0):

did u tried this way?

```
SAXParserImpl saxparser = new SAXParserImpl();
ResponseHandler handler = new ResponseHandler();
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlresp.getBytes());

public class ResponseHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, 
                           String qName,Attributes attributes) {}
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        {          
            tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
        }
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, 
                       String qName) throws SAXException    {}
}
```